# Shorter way to check if true in Python list comprehension expression (x for x if x shorter)

Tags: python

Is it possible to write it shorter? I mostly interested in not writing "r[0].value" twice.

```
    (r[0].value for r in sheet.range(USERROLELIST) if r[0].value)
```

if r[0].value -- to check that it != None

Sheet.range is from openpyxl module.

Comment: Questions like this are better suited for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(None, sheet.range(USERROLELIST))
```

Comment: This checks if `r` itself isn't `None`, not its `value`.

Comment: This should be `filter(None, (r[0].value for r in sheet.range(USERROLELIST)))`